# Do we encourage nonsense questions?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, answer-quality

There's no way around it: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390869/code-optimizationing-of-python) <s>is stupid</s> would, if it had been posted years ago, have gotten closed as "not a real question." It shows two code snippets and asks whether the one that does less stuff is faster. There's no explanation of why the performance is important, there's no attempt at testing timing, there's no attempt at critical thinking ("does it take time to do stuff?"). Here's the original version of the question in its entirety:

> Is there any difference between following two code snippets? and Which
>   is a faster and Why?
>
> case 1:
>
> ```
> def func():
>         a = 42
>         return a
> ```
>
> case 2:
>
> ```
> def func():
>         return 42
> ```

Anyone who can't answer this for themselves is going to ask a new question, because they won't be able to find this post.

However, it's getting upvotes and has a highly-upvoted answer.

This is downright embarrassing. Do we have any quality standards at all?

Comment: If this was C++ and I actually know what is going on I would probably DV the Q and leave a comment along the lines of *Any decent compiler should create the same code.  You should compile the code and check the assembly to see for yourself*.  To me it is a lack of research effort (did not check the assembly).

Comment: @NathanOliver: But it is python and not C++. And in python these two code samples will not lead to the same result. I agree that the question is not optimal, but could be rephrased to a more useful: "Why do these two samples not result in the same assembly?".

Comment: @BDL But they still could have looked up how to compare the generated code and then tried it.  After doing that if they came to SO and said they had these two codes with the disassembly and wanted to know why the compiler did not optimize the first to the second then I think that would be a great question.  I just feel not checking the disassembly first, themselves, is a reason to DV the Q.

Comment: I agree this question isn't great, and this is somewhat unrelated, but do you have any clear litmus test for quality standards yourself Tigerhawk? Because taking a cursory glance at your Answers page, I expected to see what I would consider _very_ high quality questions being answered, given that you don't hesitate to downvote & leave a canned-comment on every answer for just about everything else... but I'm having some trouble seeing the distinction.

Comment: For instance, recently you answered [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163451/testing-to-see-if-a-variable-equals-something-and-then-if-it-does-then-make-it-e) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43105005/python-while-for-if-statements), but DV/can-commented [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43088964/remove-common-characters-or-duplicates-in-a-string). What is the distinction?

Comment: It seems a perfectly good question to me. My guess is that the compiler would produce the same code for both by optimising the first one, but, not being a SW engineer, I don't _know_ that. And I wouldn't have a clue at how to look at assembly code: why do you think the asker of this question would know?

Comment: I personally believe there is no "stupid" question. You are right, there's no attempt of providing extra thoughts or timing test- and THAT is what not ok about this question.
But if we take that line of code, and compare the way it works in C/Ruby- the difference can teach a lot about both languages.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor Because it is his job to find that out. StackOverflow is no "I'm too lazy to do research myself, let others do that for me" page. ___You___ do your research and if you stuck you _may_ come here and ask (... and you include your research results in the question).

Comment: I don't think you can expect a user with a rep of about 200 to analyse the assembler code generated by the compiler to check for him or herself.

Comment: @SteveIves Rep is a measure of experience with the site, not experience as a programmer.

Comment: @Tom If that is the case (In the ideal world) then there wouldn't be any questions at all. If you, or any person on the internet can answer it, the OP can do his research and eventually find out the answer, maybe after weeks, months, years, 10 years etc. It is also a matter of finding "experts"  and finding answers and solving problems in a reasonable amount of time. I'm not saying **"basic research"** is not important. I'm saying expecting someone to dissect bite-code and otherwise calling him "stupid"  is a bit too much... Not everyone has the same expertise

Comment: @SteveIves FWIW [I'm at 160 rep and I did for my first question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652707/why-does-the-behavior-of-overloaded-member-functions-differ-from-the-behavior-of)

Comment: @Servy and some times we even have to put that measure in doubt.

Comment: @Servy True - maybe a better point is that you can't expect someone who asks a question like that to check the generated assembler code.. :-) to someone more experienced, it's obvious that before it can `return 42` it'll have to store the 42 somewhere, (probably a register, maybe in storage) and will probably be a bit quicker than returning a variable, but that real-world differences will be negligible.

Comment: @Braiam By experience I just mean *how much* you've used the site, not how effectively you're able to use the site.  Some people have used the site a ton and still don't how how to use it properly, or choose not to use it properly (or vice versa).

Comment: @SteveIves Sure, but you *could* expect such a person to do some simple searches on the topic, as questions like this have been asked *many* times, or to run a few experiments themselves to test it, etc.

Comment: @Servy I know - a simple experiment where you do both 1,000s or 1,000,000s of times would suffice, but we come across people who ask 'How do i know if my function is even being called?' and act as though you are a genius when you suggest putting in a `print 'function called'` statement. Some people struggle with programming and when you have more experience, it's really hard to put yourself in their place.

Comment: @SteveIves It doesn't take years of experience to learn how to print text to the screen.

Comment: @Servy you are right, but learning that the display can be used as a useful debugging tool is a different type of experience.

Comment: @NathanOliver The notion that the assembly is going to tell you anything about the answer to this question is a fundamental misunderstanding about computer programming. You could use a good answer to this question.

Comment: @SaggingRufus Yes, again, one that doesn't take years of experience to learn.

Comment: @Servy based on some of the people I have worked with I will respectfully disagree, BUT I do agree that it shouldn't take years of experience, however it seems to.

Comment: In my experience, there are 10 types of programmers: those that are helpful, and those that are condescending...

Comment: You have to admit though, people seem to ask about performance concerns in absurdly many situations (the vast majority of which involve two functionally different things that cannot be compared for performance in the first place)...

Comment: @TJ I wonder why you ignored the "if you stuck" part.

Comment: @Tom, Servy and the other close voters: I really wonder why you closed the question although the answer and votings here clearly indicate that this is an acceptable question.

Comment: @BDL Because I don't think that this question is acceptable.

Comment: @Tom: Then write a competing answer here and try to get a community majority instead of working against what we discuss here.

Comment: I'm curious as to why the meta-style voting approach is playing out so broadly on the original question. Regardless of whether or not people agree with this post; surely the original post does not merit 33 upvotes and 21 downvotes, and counting. Since this post was broadly about the integrity of SO, it's disappointing that people on both sides of the fence are walking all over that with overblown voting on the OP who, note, asked for none of this.

Comment: @BDL 29 People (who supported Marks answer) Are the majority? Ok :).

Comment: @Tom: Yes. Since only 5 voted against it...

Comment: I want to upvote this question, but the way its worded prevents me from doing so.  I agree, the question is basically trivia (and bad at that, as it depends on the implementation of the compiler, which I gather is significant in Python land), and answerable by using a disassembler, and therefore is off topic.  I guess the python folks like digging through their belly lint :/

Comment: The original question (rather than this meta) seems neat enough to me as it provided a window into a basic behavior of a language that I don't usually use.  It's strange to think that someone would get so upset over such a question when, judging by the votes, folks generally thought it was fairly interesting.

Comment: @Tom The person is already stuck because he doesn't know how to inspect the bitecode... So he comes and asks the python experts if anyone already know how python compiler handles this... Seems fine to me.

Comment: The question that we discuss here after editing seems good for me now, that it asks for whether it compiles to the same bytecode.

Answer (score 121):

This is not a nonsense question. It's a perfectly reasonable question that I didn't know the answer to despite having been a professional Python programmer for years.

(It was admittedly badly-titled and therefore unlikely to be useful to future readers in its initial incarnation, but [Josh Caswell's edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43390869/revisions) took care of that fine.)

Your objections seem to be twofold:

1. **The answer is obvious, and therefore asking the question is stupid.**

   I disagree. In many languages, the two code snippets exhibited *would* compile down to exactly the same lower-level code. To recognise that this isn't the case in Python, one either needs to have at least a basic knowledge of the optimisation powers of Python's compiler, or needs to have the knowledge required to analyse the byte code produced by it in order to see that it is different for these two snippets. Plenty of Python programmers won't have the knowledge required to do either of these things, because they've simply never needed to. I am such a person, even though I have 500 upvotes across my Python contributions here and have worked with the language for years. You're assuming that this knowledge is basic and common to all Python programmers when it *really, really isn't.*

   And even if none of that were the case, basic questions are allowed here. *"The stupid asker is stupid for not already knowing the answer to his question, so he shouldn't be allowed to ask it"* is not one of our close reasons, and it shouldn't be.
2. **There is no point in knowing the answer to the question anyway**

   This doesn't necessarily seem true. I agree that it would be a strange scenario indeed where the cost of an *assignment* had a performance impact that mattered (although I'm not convinced that it could *literally never* matter), but this is an interesting question just as a case study in the powers of Python's byte code compiler, and is useful in that capacity. Having read the answer, I understand more about Python's byte code compilation than I did before. As such, the question was useful to me.

I see no reason for this question to be downvoted or closed, at all.

Comment: This. What I wanted to say too, both as a moderator *and* as a [tag:python] regular. If something seems obvious to you, step aside for a moment and assess your own assumptions first.

Comment: 1. The question was not, "do these compile to the same byte code".  The question was which one is faster.  This is answered by simply running the two snippets, something that any programmer interested in the answer is going to be capable of doing.  2. You say that it matters, and then immediately follow it up by saying that it doesn't matter.  That you were *entertained* by it, despite it not being useful, doesn't change that.

Comment: @Ðаn: Then the OP should provide examples that exemplify the problem. This one does not.

Comment: @Servy no one is saying that question was perfect and did not need editing. They are saying the basis of the question aren't enough to close and that it is a valid question. In my environment, I don't always have the luxury of just be able to run what ever test code I want, so I sympathise with the asker of the question.

Comment: @Servy: Naive performance tests in a single environment are generally not useful. Much better to have an understanding of what's actually going on.

Comment: @SaggingRufus But it's *not* an appropriate question, and it's problems aren't just trivially fixed with a surface level edit.  If you're not in a position of being able to run any code at all then why would you *care* about the answer to the question?  Any time that you'd need to know the answer to the question would be a time where you *are* in a position to actually run the code.

Comment: The questions wasn't presented very well at the beginning (and one of the edits did take care of that) but it was relatively clear what was asked and it definitely was answerable. Time measurements are (imho) nothing that was needed here since it would only test one configuration in one environment, while it was possible to answer the question in a very general way. Analyzing assemblies on the other hand is something I really wouldn't expect a python programmer to know. I even doubt that a lot of C++ programmers have ever looked at the disassembly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If you want to actually understand which performs better, you have that the other way around.  If you run the two snippets you *know* what the performance difference is.  If you ask a stranger on the internet what they think the performance difference will be, then you've only learned what some stranger on the internet thinks the difference will be.

Comment: @Servy That's not what I said, of course I can run code and do tests. In my position these things are planned out and we don't make change for change sake. I am also so run off my feet with actual development work that there is no way I could take time out of my day to set a testbed to test something that may or may not be implemented into my codeset. Because of this, I would ask a question to the community.

Comment: @SaggingRufus "I couldn't be bothered to do the work myself, so I'll just ask other people to do it for me" isn't actually an appropriate reason to ask a question on SO.  The help center specifically says that people are expected to be doing their research and trying to find an answer to their question before asking on SO, only asking if they're unable to solve their own problem, not asking becuase they can't be bothered to solve the problem.

Comment: @Servy: But if you ask a community of people with a strong peer review ethos (SO) whether there's a difference between the examples (which the OP did in the first revision), that's very different from asking some random stranger or relying on your own naive test. That's asking for what's happening under-the-covers. Which is what the OP got.

Comment: @Servy again, not what I said. I now understand your position completely.

Comment: @SaggingRufus That's *exactly* what you said.  You said you were too busy to take the time to answer the question, so you asked other people to do it for you *purely* so that you don't have to do it yourself.  How is that not what you said?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's not meaningfully different.  So you're asking a group of people what they all think will happen, rather than doing the test and *knowing* what will happen.

Comment: @Servy: Well, we just disagree about that. The peer review aspect is *crucially* different, in my view. And I think the result clearly supports my view. You clearly think otherwise. That's fine, you don't have to agree with me, nor I with you.

Comment: @Servy no, I said I am not allowed to change the code set to test these types of things AND I am overrun and couldn't do it "just to test it" even if I wanted to. When I want to make a change I need to justify it first, and I don't have environments where I can do whatever I want because the mood strikes. So if I was in a position where I was trying to find an answer like the asker, I would have to ask someone because I need justification to make my change or even be authorized to stop my work to look into it.

Comment: @SaggingRufus That's *not* what you said.  You said, "I am also so run off my feet with actual development work that there is no way I could take time out of my day to set a testbed to test something".  You didn't say, "I'm not allowed to even run any tests without justifying to other people that I know the test should be performed.

Comment: @ Mark - Ðаn does have a point that this only addresses the specific question flagged, not the overall question of whether we encourage poor-quality questions. It uses a poor example (in my view), but the fundamental question, while intemperately expressed, is a valid one. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'll leave the general case for other answerers to address, if they wish to. My *personal* view - about which I'm much less certain than I am about this single question - is that the community *generally* does a decent job of being welcoming to good content and hostile to bad content, and that the loudest voices complaining about our lack of standards are - as in this particular case - usually advocating for arbitrary or unhelpfully harsh standards that I don't agree with. So in a sense I guess my answer does address the general case, just by way of a case study.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder But fundamental to "do we encourage poor-quality questions" is "what counts as a 'poor-quality question'?"  It seems to be that the community disagrees with TigerhawkT3 on what a 'poor-quality question' is. If we can't agree on what we're talking about, how can we ever come to consensus on what to do about it? -- If the example presented in this meta question doesn't encapsulate what TigerhawkT3 (or others) thinks a 'poor-quality question' is, then this is a poor-quality meta question. :-)

Comment: @R.M.: Indeed. Amusingly, the question might fall short of the quality standard it promotes, by using only a single example. :-) Or not, if this is a bang-on accurate example. And Mark's comment above, along the same lines, is well-taken too. If the example is emblematic of the problem described by the question, addressing the example addresses the question.